# Change tomcat catalina logs owner

Tags: linux, tomcat, catalina

Is there any way to change the owner of Tomcat catalina logs from *root* to my current (non-root) user in an Ubuntu server?

Tomcat needs to be started using a cronjob in root. I want to avoid having to type *sudo* every time I want to check logs.

Answer (score 1):

Sure there is.  *Do not run tomcat as root* to begin with. This way any problem/issue in your web facing application immediately has the highest privileges possible.

If the cron job runs as root: root can drop its privileges and start processes as another user account

Comment: Do you reckon Tomcat wouldn't need root privileges during any time in its lifecycle?

Comment: If an internet-accessible process needs to have root privileges, then the architecture is wrong and extremely risky.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks @olaf-kock . Never looked at it that way. I'll change the tomcat user to a non-root user.
Also, if you could post the steps to achieve my original intention, that could help someone in the future.

Comment: These _are_ my recommended steps